# Finding type in python - TypeError 'unicode' object is not callable

Tags: python, google-app-engine, types

I'm trying to make sure an object is a string type in Python (for google app engine).  I'm doing this so that I can change it to a `db.Text` type if its more than 500 bytes.  However, I keep getting the error: `TypeError 'unicode' object is not callable`

```
    if type(value) in types.StringTypes and len(value) > 499:
        value = db.Text(value)
    setattr(entity, key, value)
```

What should I use to test if the type of the object is a string?

Comment: is `value` the variable that you are trying to change into a `db.Text`?

Comment: Why are you doing this conversion? Does your column need to be indexed at all? If so, why doesn't it matter that anything over 512 bytes isn't indexed?

Comment: Hey Nick, the reason I'm doing the conversation is because an exception was being thrown whenever the field was greater than 500 bytes because apparently you have to switch over to the unindexed "text" property over 500 bytes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you calling `types.StringTypes` ? It's a tuple:

```
>>> types.StringTypes
(<type 'str'>, <type 'unicode'>)
```

Use `isinstance(value, types.StringTypes) and len(value) > 499`

Answer (score 6):

I think you just need to remove the parentheses from `types.StringTypes`, since it is a tuple (and not callable, hence the error). Either that, or your code is actually using `StringType`, which means your code is making a new string instance instead of returning the `str` type. Either way, it looks like a typo. See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/types.html#types.StringTypes).

Comment: I tried it both ways, for some reason it was still giving me the error.  This worked though: isinstance(value, types.StringTypes)

Answer (score 1):

Greg Haskins is right

```
>>> types.StringTypes()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
>>> types.StringTypes
(<type 'str'>, <type 'unicode'>)
```

Could you do

```
if type(variable_name) == type("")
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**  Oops!  I was looking at [types.StringType](http://docs.python.org/library/types.html#types.StringType), instead of [types.StringTypes](http://docs.python.org/library/types.html#types.StringTypes), so the test could be:

```
if type(value) in types.StringTypes and len(value) > 499:
    value = db.Text(value)
```

Where the main problem with the OP code was the presence of the parens at the end of types.StringTypes.

**Original:**  A few problems here:

- If value holds a Unicode, testing it with type() will return [types.UnicodeType](http://docs.python.org/library/types.html#types.UnicodeType)
- The types.StringType is a constant, not a function, so drop the parentheses.
- Furthermore, types.StringType isn't iterable, so test against it with == or is.

Thus, your test could look something like:

```
if ((type(value) == types.StringType) or (type(value) == types.UnicodeType)) and len(value) > 499:
    value = db.Text(value)
```

Comment: @DutrowLLC:  See my updated answer for using with types.StringTypes

Comment: "if type(value) in types.StringTypes and len(value) > 499:" still throws the same error.  Maybe you were right about it not being iterable?

Comment: or use `isinstance(value, basestring)`.

Comment: @DutrowLLC:  Are you sure you're using types.StringTypes (ending with 's') and not types.StringType (no 's' at the end)?  That's what led my first answer a bit astray.  Also, if you're using an old version of Python, you might get that error, as the documentation indicates that types.StringTypes was introduced in 2.2.

Comment: Yeah, I doulble-checked, I was using types.StringTypes.  I'm using Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I prefer
`isinstance(object_to_be_checked, str)`

Comment: Be careful with this. In python 2.x this won't work for unicode strings or other string-like objects. It's better to do `isinstance(obj, basestring)`, which will still fail for non built-in string-like objects, but will work with unicode strings and "regular" strings.